# How to map JSON object returned from REST controller to html page

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I need to know how data returned from the Spring MVC REST controller attaches to html page and what the Spring configuration do we have to do this.
The browser just prints this data out without view and that's all. 
I have some Spring configurations to do it but unfortunatelly it doesn't work.

Comment: Normally you have a html page which sends ajax calls and gets JSON response. Based on the response page updates parts e.g. renders table. There are plenty of ways to reflect returned data on page.

Comment: Post what you have tried, we can guide you from there

Comment: Please add your code

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to create a spring web-mvc application with a correct configuration that will run without errors. There are plenty of tutorials on how to do it. After that, if you wish to get json data using your rest controllers, the most popular way to do it is by using javascript and the JQuery library. Using them you can make ajax calls to your api. There are plenty of tutorials on how to achive this again. Finnaly, your data will be on the client side and you can manage them (render them in your html-dom etc) using javascript and JQuery again.